# Sorting an NSMutableDictionary of custom objects whose values may contain duplicates

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary of custom objects of type "Fraction", which is composed of a numerator variable of type int, and a denominator variable also of type int.  I am able to sort all of the values after they have been pulled from the NSMutableDictionary, and put into an NSArray.  However, I have just discovered a new problem.  Because my NSMutableDictionary is a collection of "Fraction" objects, it is very possible that some of these objects may be duplicates of one another, which means finding the respective "key" value from the original NSMutableDictionary will also cause problems.  How do I overcome this?  I have an NSMutableDictionary that contains NSStrings for keys, and custom "Fraction" objects for values.  I have an NSArray that contains these custom "Fraction" objects, sorted from biggest, to smallest.  The problem is that some of these objects may be the same (e.g. 1/2, 1/3, 1/3, 1/4).  What I would like to know is how to pull each key for its respective "Fraction" object, despite the fact that there are duplicates?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to obtain two (distinct) keys if there are two `1/3` fractions in the dictionary?

Comment: Correct.  If I have a key named "Joe" with a corresponding value of 1/3, and another key named "Larry" also with a corresponding value of 1/3, if I have a sorted array of Fraction objects, how do I pull both keys, and associate each key with a value of 1/3?

Comment: @sydefa Then have a look at the documentation of `NSDictionary`. It has a method named `allKeysForObject:`.

Comment: @H2CO3: Thanks very much.  I think I figured out what to do using this method.  If there are multiple keys for a particular object while iterating the array, then an array with a count of > 1 will be returned, which means I will simply have to iterate over it as well.  Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, correct. [15 chars]

Comment: How do I award you the answer?  Can you post your solution as an answer so I can award it to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all keys for a particular object, use the `allKeysForObject:` method of `NSDictionary`.